# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression

Tags: swiftui

I have a db query I am running depending on the filter of a segmented picker. The issue is when I run the code, it errors, saying that the compiler cannot type-check in a reasonable time. Any help is appreciated:

Errors on the line
return try db.prepare(query).map { .init(

Previously, the code worked when running without filters and a switch statement. I need the switch statement to filter different db queries based on the user input in the segmented picker. The code looks simple?

Code:

```
import Foundation
import SQLite

class AirportsDataSource {
    
    var db: Connection?
    var filterOption: String = "IATA"
    var query: NSURLQueryItem
    
    init() {
        
        do {
            guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airports", withExtension: "sqlite") else 
            {
                print("Could not find the airports.sqlite file in the app bundle.")
                return
            }
            db = try Connection(fileURL.path)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func search(_ text: String) -> [Airport] {
        guard let db = db else { return [] }
        do {
            let airports = Table("mytable")
            let airportId = Expression<Int?>("airportId")
            let codeIataAirport = Expression<String?>("codeIataAirport")
            let codeICAOAirport = Expression<String?>("codeICAOAirport")
            let codeIataCity = Expression<String?>("codeIataCity")
            let nameAirportName = Expression<String?>("nameAirport")
            let latitude = Expression<String?>("latitudeAirport")
            let longitude = Expression<String?>("longitudeAirport")
          
            switch filterOption {
                case "IATA":
                   let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            codeIataAirport.like("\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(codeIataAirport)
                        .limit(100)
                case "ICAO":
                     let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            codeICAOAirport.like("\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(codeIataAirport)
                        .limit(100)
                case "Airport Name":
                     let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            codeIataCity.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(codeIataAirport)
                       .limit(100)
                default:
                     let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            codeIataAirport.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            codeICAOAirport.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            codeIataCity.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(codeIataAirport.asc)
                        .limit(100)
            }
          
            return try db.prepare(query).map { .init(
                id: $0[airportId] ?? .random(in: 11000...12000),
                name: $0[nameAirportName] ?? "N/A",
                code: $0[codeIataAirport] ?? "N/A",
                lat: $0[latitude] ?? "0.0",
                long: $0[longitude] ?? "0.0"
            ) }
            
            
        } catch {
            print("error reading table", error)
            return []
        }
    }
    
}

struct Airport: Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let code: String
    let lat: String
    let long: String
}
```

Not sure what to try here. How can I break this down. Ii tried running the code with no filters and it worked fine. however I have a strong use case to filter the fields based on the picker input. The filterOption is working fine and displays the correct filter selected by the user.

Comment: Please post also your view code with the picker you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your switch statement, each case declares `query` with `let`. So `query` goes out of scope at the end of each `case`.

Try declaring `query` before the `switch` and remove the `let` inside each `case`:

```swift
let query: NSURLQueryItem // or whatever type it should be

switch filterOption {
    case "IATA":
        query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            // etc
    case "ICAO":
        query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            // etc
    case "Airport Name":
        query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            // etc
    default:
        query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            // etc
}

// Now query can be executed
```