# Cannot find variable in scope. SwiftUI Switch Statement

Tags: swiftui, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that I need clarification on here. The error returned from xCode Compiler is * Cannot find 'query' in scope * from the code attached. I have a series of let statements depending on the filterOptions coming in correctly.
I can't find why it would say the variable is not in scope. Any help appreciated

```
class AirportsDataSource {
    
    var db: Connection?
    var filterOption: String = "IATA"
    
    init() {
        
        do {
            guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airports", withExtension: "sqlite") else 
            {
                print("Could not find the airports.sqlite file in the app bundle.")
                return
            }
            db = try Connection(fileURL.path)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func search(_ text: String) -> [Airport] {
        guard let db = db else { return [] }
        
        do {
            let airports = Table("mytable")
            let airportId = Expression<Int?>("airportId")
            let codeIataAirport = Expression<String?>("codeIataAirport")
            let codeICAOAirport = Expression<String?>("codeICAOAirport")
            let name = Expression<String?>("name")
            let nameAirportName = Expression<String?>("nameAirport")
            let latitude = Expression<String?>("latitudeAirport")
            let longitude = Expression<String?>("longitudeAirport")
            
            switch filterOption {
                case "IATA":
                    let query = airports
                       .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                       .where(
                           codeICAOAirport.like("%\(text)%")
                       )
                       .order(codeICAOAirport)
                       .limit(100)
                case "ICAO":
                    let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            name.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(codeICAOAirport)
                        .limit(100)
                case "Airport Name":
                     let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            name.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(nameAirportName)
                       .limit(100)
                default:
                     let query = airports
                        .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
                        .where(
                            codeIataAirport.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            codeICAOAirport.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            name.like("%\(text)%") ||
                            nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
                        )
                        .order(codeIataAirport.asc)
                        .limit(100)
            }
            
            return try db.prepare(query).map
            { .init(
                id: $0[airportId] ?? .random(in: 11000...12000),
                name: $0[nameAirportName] ?? "N/A",
                code: $0[codeIataAirport] ?? "N/A",
                lat: $0[latitude] ?? "0.0",
                long: $0[longitude] ?? "0.0"
            ) }
            
          
        } catch {
            print("error reading table", error)
            return []
        }
    }
    
}
```

I was expecting that the Expressions and db query be built up depending on the switch statement and then the db query to run the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `query` locally within the `switch` cases. A local variable is only visible inside its enclosing braces or – in this case – in the scope of the case.

I don't know the type of `query` but you have to declare it above the `switch` statement and remove the `let` occurrences inside the cases

```
let query : Query // no optional needed
switch filterOption {
    case "IATA":
        query = airports
           .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
           .where(
               codeICAOAirport.like("%\(text)%")
           )
           .order(codeICAOAirport)
           .limit(100)
    case "ICAO":
        query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            .where(
                name.like("%\(text)%") ||
                nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
            )
            .order(codeICAOAirport)
            .limit(100)
    case "Airport Name":
         query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            .where(
                name.like("%\(text)%") ||
                nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
            )
            .order(nameAirportName)
           .limit(100)
    default:
         query = airports
            .select(airportId, codeIataAirport, nameAirportName, latitude, longitude)
            .where(
                codeIataAirport.like("%\(text)%") ||
                codeICAOAirport.like("%\(text)%") ||
                name.like("%\(text)%") ||
                nameAirportName.like("%\(text)%")
            )
            .order(codeIataAirport.asc)
            .limit(100)
}

return try db.prepare(query).map
{ .init(
    id: $0[airportId] ?? .random(in: 11000...12000),
    name: $0[nameAirportName] ?? "N/A",
    code: $0[codeIataAirport] ?? "N/A",
    lat: $0[latitude] ?? "0.0",
    long: $0[longitude] ?? "0.0"
) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I place this outside of the { as detailed in your response I then get cannot find type Query in scope also

Comment: Then your code is not the real code. My suggestion cannot cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same as (or similar to) the code you posted earlier in [The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77291961/20386264).

This time, you appear to have removed `var query: NSURLQueryItem` from the class, which is probably why the error message has changed. But the error itself is the same: each `query` goes out of scope at the end of each `case`.

You need to declare `query` before the `switch` and then assign it in the case statements. See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77293216/20386264) for full details.